# AWS DynamoDB Encryption Unable to parse HTTP response content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm using DirectKmsMaterialProvider of aws-dynamodb-encryption-java to encrypt my data to be stored to dynamodb but upon calling ***mapper.save(objectToSave)*** I get the error below:

```
 final EncryptionMaterialsProvider provider = new DirectKmsMaterialProvider(awskmsClient,
                    awsKMSAliasKey);
            mapper  = new DynamoDBMapper(dynamoDBClient, mapperConfig,
                    new AttributeEncryptor(provider));
```

Error:

```
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Unable to parse HTTP response content (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 302; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.AttributeEncryptor.transform(AttributeEncryptor.java:67)[63:express-server:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.transformAttributes(DynamoDBMapper.java:2414)[63:express-server:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.transformAttributeUpdates(DynamoDBMapper.java:2446)[63:express-server:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.access$200(DynamoDBMapper.java:185)[63:express-server:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.doUpdateItem(DynamoDBMapper.java:1080)[63:express-server:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$2.executeLowLevelRequest(DynamoDBMapper.java:795)[63:express-server:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper$SaveObjectHandler.execute(DynamoDBMapper.java:974)[63:express-server:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:824)[63:express-server:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper.save(DynamoDBMapper.java:669)[63:express-server:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your KMS endpoint is correct
for example:

```
AWSKMSClient awsKMSClient = new AWSKMSClient(new InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider());
awsKMSClient.setEndpoint("kms.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com");
```

refer to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#kms_region